# Backend/Database Advice Sought for Scheduling Website

Tags: php, mysql, database, vue.js, mariadb

I've run the website for a local youth sports organization for the past five years or so ([www.parochialathleticleague.org](http://www.parochialathleticleague.org)).  I designed it myself from scratch, but it's quickly become quite outdated and I'm about to begin a complete redesign from the ground up.

For the frontend, I'm going to be learning Vue.js and combining that with a lightweight CSS framework like Bulma (probably in the form of Buefy).

For the backend, however, I would like to ask for opinions/advice:

Currently, the website uses a scheduling system that utilizes PHP scripting to access a MySQL database with all of the schedules, standings, accounts, etc.  This has worked well enough, but it's quite cumbersome and time consuming, especially importing and formatting the various schedules each season from Excel spreadsheets.  What a pain in the neck.

I was simply going to move to MariaDB as the database format, but that feels like more of the same workflow.  I'd like to really think outside the box and look for creative ways to modernize the infrastructure and make my life a little easier.  Keeping up with emerging web technology is very challenging and surely there many ideas that currently elude me in trying to plan this.

Comment: A relational database is going to give you a relatively similar workflow. If you're looking to use an "outside the box" type solutions, perhaps look into Google's APIs and use their calendar and spreadsheet systems directly? That would allow easier editing for non-technical admins, but allow you to display the data however you'd like.

Comment: This is a bit to opinion based a question.  But I will say that I would more focus on inventive ways of making the users life easier rather than your own.

Comment: @RyanKozak I appreciate your suggestion and it's definitely outside the box. Thank you. Unfortunately, it's too simple of a solution for our needs. Wondering if it would make any sense to store this kind of data (for example: [link](http://www.parochialathleticleague.org/schedules_bb_northa.html?league=northa&table=basketball_1718_northa)) in a NoSQL solution?   The league director has to first create the schedules, import them into a referee consignment software and export them back to me in an Excel spreadsheet, which I then have to prep all of the tables and scripts for format, etc.

Comment: @712Jefferson perhaps [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) would be easier for you to work with? Mongo uses collections, rather than tables, which allows you to more easily add your data and query relationships. I've Mongo mostly when storing data collected by scrapers which query JSON API's. The JSON can be inserted directly into a collection without having to build a database schema first. You'd still need to convert your CSV's to JSON and vice versa.